# pandas rellenar columna condicionalmente entre varios valores de otra columna

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe que contiene una columna de eventos y quiero añadirle una de estado de este modo:

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ eventType   ║ estado      ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ stop        ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ algo        ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ algo        ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ otra cosa   ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ evento      ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║             ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ algo        ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ otra cosa   ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ start       ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║             ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ algo        ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ evento      ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ otro evento ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ otra cosa   ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ stop        ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ evento      ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ evento      ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ otro evento ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ algo        ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ start       ║ 1           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ algo algo   ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ lo que sea  ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ evento      ║ 0           ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

la idea es que cuando encuentre un start empiece a rellenar con 1 y cuando se encuentre un stop con 0 empezando a rellenar con 0 hasta el primer start.
La columna de eventos tiene varios eventos que paran la máquina y varios que la ponen en marcha (aunque la mayoria tienen stop o start en el nombre)
¿hay algún modo de hacerlo sin usar un bucle for?

Solucionado:
Al final he hecho una función:

```
actual = 0
def def_estado(row):
    global actual
    events = {'start': 1, 'stop': 0}
    if row['eventType'] in events:
        actual = events[row['eventType']]
    return actual
```

Y luego se la paso a la la columna con apply

```
df['estado'] = df.apply(def_estado, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### El problema de los `DataFrame`s:

De manera nativa si puedes generar una colección de datos en base a los elementos de otra, lo que pasa es que la columna de un `DataFrame` no es una colección de datos nativa del lenguaje. Si embargo se pueden extraer datos de un `DataFrame` como una colección de datos nativa.

> ¿hay algún modo de hacerlo sin usar un bucle for?

Existe la función implementada [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel.

### ¿Cómo se hace?

**El `DataFrame` que se tiene**

En este caso voy a usar un diccionario como manera de creación del `DataFrame`, de `n * 1` de dimensión. Los valores de la única columna provienen de esta secuencia:

```
secuencia = ["Inicio",None,None,None,"Final",None,None,None,"Inicio",None,None,None,None,"Indefinido",None,"Final",None,0,"Inicio","Final","Inicio",0,None,0,"Final"]
```

Donde:

- *"Inicio" representa el inicio de un evento*
- *"Final" representa el final de un evento*
- *Cualquier otro valor representa la longitud del evento*

Como dije, si se genera un `DataFrame`así

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"EventType": secuencia})
```

se obtiene una columna con varias filas

```
     EventType
0       Inicio
1         None
2         None
3         None
4        Final
5         None
6         None
7         None
8       Inicio
9         None
10        None
11        None
12        None
13  Indefinido
14        None
15       Final
16        None
17           0
18      Inicio
19       Final
20      Inicio
21           0
22        None
23           0
24       Final
```

**Extrayendo la columna del DataFrame**

Por suerte, podemos acceder a los valores de una columna en específico al igual de comos nos referimos a los valores de una llave en un diccionario. Por medio de el atributo `values` y la función `list()` se puede obtener en formato de lista los valores de la columna en cuestión. Por lo tanto, **se pueden almacenar dichos valores en tipo de dato nativo.**

```
EventType = list(df["EventType"].values)
```

se obtiene

```
['Inicio', None, None, None, 'Final', None, None, None, 'Inicio', None, None, None, None, 'Indefinido', None, 'Final', None, 0, 'Inicio', 'Final', 'Inicio', 0, None, 0, 'Final']
```

**Generando la nueva columna del `DataFrame`**

Según la especificación de `map()`

```
map(function, iterable, ...)
```

Requiere de una función y un iterable

- **La función**

Bien puede ser definida o una función anónima, hay que decir que es más conveniente usar una función `lambda` anónima. Esto ya que de esa manera al función quedará como una expresión, su tiempo de vida es solo el necesario.

Es necesario que tenga un parámetro, para que itere de uno en uno y ejecute las instrucciones con base a un elemento. Si se usaran más argumentos la cantidad de elementos que se usan por ciclo sería equivalente a la cantidad de argumentos.

- **El iterable**

Si queremos generar otra lista en base a los elementos de `EventType`, es lo que vamos a usar. Se debe de saber cuando empieza o termina un evento. Por la tanto no hay más remedio que definir una función (con una variable de ámbito global):

```
x = None

def event(n):
    global x

    if n == "Inicio":
        x = 1
    elif n == "Final":
        x = 0
    else:
        x = x

    return x
```

De esta manera puede perdurar el valor de `x` después de cada iteración que hace `map()`. La lista se tendría que generar con una `lambda` de un argumento, para que de esta forma todos los elementos de `secuencia` pasen por la función `event()`

```
state = list(map(lambda n: event(n),secuencia))
```

Esta expresión, significa añadir un elemento a `State` por cada elemento en `EventType`. Este elemento será el retornado por `event()`.

Se estaría obteniendo esto

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

### Obteniendo el `DataFrame` final:

Se podría montar otro `DataFrame` nuevo desde cero, pero es mejor reutilizar el actual y añadir una serie como columna:

```
df["State"] = pd.Series(state)
```

A la hora de imprimir por pantalla con `print(df)` se obtiene

```
     EventType  State
0       Inicio      1
1         None      1
2         None      1
3         None      1
4        Final      0
5         None      0
6         None      0
7         None      0
8       Inicio      1
9         None      1
10        None      1
11        None      1
12        None      1
13  Indefinido      1
14        None      1
15       Final      0
16        None      0
17           0      0
18      Inicio      1
19       Final      0
20      Inicio      1
21           0      1
22        None      1
23           0      1
24       Final      0
```

Espero te haya servido de algo, saludos.

Comment: Al final he usado una variación de la función que has señalado y luego la he mejorado con la idea del diccionario de Candid_moe.
mas info en el edit, gracias a ambos

Answer (score 1):

Es rara la exigencia de no usar `for`.

Nota: No me queda claro en que orden vienen los eventos, por lo tanto, dare dos soluciones

**Eventos en orden cronologico**

Se supone que los eventos están listados en orden cronológico: el primer evento en la columna es el más antiguo.

La función `value` retorna el valor de relleno, segùn el tipo de evento.

El diccionario `opciones` tiene como llave el texto del evento y el valor a retornar. También tiene una entrada "last", para guardar el último valor retornado.

La función `map` aplica la función `value` a toda la columna del Dataframe, produciendo un iterador. La función `list` se encarga de transformar lo anterior en una lista. Una vez que tenemos la lista, podemos agregarla como columna al DataFrame por simple asignación.

```
import pandas as pd

data = ["Inicio", "start", "fecha", "fecha",  "stop", "fecha", "fecha", "start", "fecha", "fin"]

df =  pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["EventType"])

opciones = dict(stop=0, start=1, last=0)
def value(texto):
    if texto in opciones:
        opciones['last'] = opciones[texto]
    return opciones['last']
            
df['estado'] = list(map(value, df["EventType"]))
print(df)
```

produce:

```
  EventType  estado
0    Inicio       0
1     start       1
2     fecha       1
3     fecha       1
4      stop       0
5     fecha       0
6     fecha       0
7     start       1
8     fecha       1
9       fin       1
```

**Eventos en orden inverso**

Si los eventos vienen en orden inverso (el primero es el más nuevo), vamos a invertir la columna antes de formar la secuencia. Una vez formada la secuencia, la invierto y la agrego como columna al dataframe original.

```
import pandas as pd

data = ["Inicio", "start", "fecha", "fecha",  "stop", "fecha", "fecha", "start", "fecha", "fin"]

df =  pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["EventType"])
opciones = dict(stop=0, start=1, last=0)
def value(texto):
    if texto in opciones:
        opciones['last'] = opciones[texto]
    return opciones['last']
            
events = df["EventType"].values[::-1]
df["estado"] = list(pd.Series(list(map(value, events))))[::-1]
print(df)

produce:

  EventType  estado
0    Inicio       1
1     start       1
2     fecha       0
3     fecha       0
4      stop       0
5     fecha       1
6     fecha       1
7     start       1
8     fecha       0
9       fin       0
```

**Observaciones**

Antes de invocar `value()` para un nuevo dataframe, hay que reinicializar `opciones['last'] = 0`